# Body parser not letting localhost load NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 




//PROBLEM LINE
    **app.use(parser.json);**
///////////////    




var todos = [];
var nextTodoItem = 1;
app.use(bodyParser.json);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //console.log("ToDo Root");
    res.send("ToDo Root");
});

//GET REQUEST TO GET ALL TODO ITEMS
        //   GET /todos

app.get('/todos', function (req, res) {
    // Need to send back the array of todos
    res.json(todos); //array is converted to JSON.
    }

);

//GET REQUEST TO GET SOME SPECIFIC TODO
        //GET todos/:id
                //Express uses : (colon) to parse data.

app.get('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
    var todoID = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    var todoObjectWithID = -1;
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        if(todo.id == todoID){
            todoObjectWithID = todos[todoID - 1];

        }
    });

    if(todoObjectWithID == -1){
        res.status(404).send();


    } else {
        res.json(todoObjectWithID); //Send the JSON of the specific todo with id requested.
    }
    console.log('Asing for todo with id of ' + req.params.id);
});


//Create a POST request to create new TODO Items.

        //POST /todos
app.post('/todos', function(req, res){
    var body = req.body;
    console.log("description");
    res.json(body);

});




//Server basic start up (port and log)

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server up and running");
});
```

I run the server with bash (Mac OS) but I go to `http://localhost:3000` nothing loads, but when I remove the `app.use(bodyParser)` it loads properly.

What is the problem in the body-parser?

This problem only occurs when I have that line, otherwise, the server runs up perfectly fine. I need that parser though, so what is my option?

Answer (score 1):

Change that line to `app.use(bodyParser.json());`